# Exibindo Imagens dentro de uma pasta, mas é possível linkar?

Tags: php

Tenho um código em PHP, que exibe todas as imagens de uma determinada pasta, porém gostaria de saber se é possível LINKAR com um `<a href="link"></a>` cada imagem(sabendo a ordem) determinando uma sequência no código ou similar a isto.
Alguém tem alguma idéia ou exemplos a partir do código abaixo?

```
<?php
$pasta = 'img/img_anuncios/';

$arquivos = glob("$pasta{*.jpg,*.png,*.gif,*.bmp}", GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($arquivos as $img){?>
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $img; ?>" id="example1"><img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="<?php echo $img; ?>" id="teste1"  style="width: 250px; height: 220px;"/></a>
<?php  }

?>
```

EDIT:

ALGO SIMILAR A ISSO (HTML):

```
<a target="_blank" href="LINK" ><img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="img/calcemp_nova.png" id="teste1" style="width: 250px; height: 220px;"></a>
<a target="_blank" href="LINK" ><img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="img/cohncor.png" id="teste1" style="width: 250px; height: 220px;"></a>
<a target="_blank" href="LINK" ><img class="mySlides w3-animate-fading" src="img/indemp_nova.png" id="teste1" style="width: 250px; height: 220px;"></a>
```

Comment: Da maneira que está ela não está linkando?

Comment: Sim, a imagem linka. Queria saber se é possível fazer um "link particular" pra cada imagem, ao invés de criar um pra cada no html.

Comment: Não consegui entender o que deseja fazer. Tem como colocar um exemplo do HTML que deveria ser gerado a partir desta lógica?

Comment: editei, coloquei o HTML. Nesse caso eu preciso ficar adicionando cada linha.

Comment: Mas seu código não gera exatamente este HTML que colocou?

Comment: Sim, gera. Acho que não estou sabendo explicar. vou tentar simplificar.
É possível linkar as imagens direcionando para um link externo( cada imagem), ao invés de linkar pra própria imagem no código PHP acima?